# Compare non consecutive fields in two different files

Tags: perl, awk, sed, compare, match

I have a File_1.txt with below data in it.

```
1234
2567
```

The second file File_2.txt has the below data in it.

```
2015-10-30,1234,zxcfgdk,kyfz
2015-10-30,2567,askjfkj,aaaa
2015-10-30,8888,bsjfjah,iojk
```

I want to compare the File_1.txt data with column2 data of File_2.txt. If it matches then redirect the entire row of File_2.txt to a seperate file. And the one's which are not matched to anothe file.

Have googled many pages. But was not of any help.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

With `awk`:

```
$ cat s.awk
BEGIN { FS="," }
NR==FNR { a[$1]; next }
$2 in a { print > "matched.txt" }
!($2 in a) { print > "missing.txt" }

$ awk -f s.awk f1 f2

$ cat missing.txt
2015-10-30,8888,bsjfjah,iojk

$ cat matched.txt
2015-10-30,1234,zxcfgdk,kyfz
2015-10-30,2567,askjfkj,aaaa
```

With `grep`:

Another possibility is simply to use grep, but you need to be sure that the values in file1 will never appear (word delimited) in file2 outside of field2:

```
$ grep -w -f f1 f2
2015-10-30,1234,zxcfgdk,kyfz
2015-10-30,2567,askjfkj,aaaa

$ grep -v -w -f f1 f2
2015-10-30,8888,bsjfjah,iojk
```

Comment: Thanks jas for your solution. Is there any other simple way of doing this ?

Comment: Thanks Jas, That's awesome and it suits my solution.